# How should I interpret this ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

```
const lerpFactor = {
    toggle: rightSide ? diff < 0 ? 0.15 : 0.1 : diff < 0 ? 0.1 : 0.15,
    title: rightSide ? diff < 0 ? 0.1 : 0.15 : diff < 0 ? 0.15 : 0.1
};
```

How should I format this so that a beginner, like me, can understand?

Comment: This is poorly coded as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with some proper indentation:

```
const lerpFactor = {
    toggle: rightSide
      ? diff < 0
          ? 0.15
          : 0.1
      : diff < 0
          ? 0.1
          : 0.15,
    title: rightSide
      ? diff < 0
          ? 0.1
          : 0.15
      : diff < 0
          ? 0.15
          : 0.1
};
```

Of course this code is still a mess that's hard to understand, beginner or not. It's meaningless (of course, that's mostly because pseudocode) and has lots of duplication. So introduce appropriately named functions that you can call to reduce both complexity and duplication, and throw in some boolean simplification:

```
function getFactor(diff, invert) {
    return invert !== (diff < 0)
      ? 0.15
      : 0.1;
}
const lerpFactor = {
    toggle: getFactor(diff, !rightSide),
    title: getFactor(diff, rightSide),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are the same for both `toggle` and `title`, so you can condense the code into a single `if`/`else` chain for both:

```
let toggle;
let title;
if (rightSide) {
  if (diff < 0) {
    toggle = 0.15;
    title = 0.1;
  } else {
    toggle = 0.1;
    title = 0.15;
  }
} else {
  if (diff < 0) {
    toggle = 0.1;
    title = 0.15;
  } else {
    toggle = 0.15;
    title = 0.1;
  }
}

const lerpFactor = { toggle, title };
```

Another option would be to assign `title` afterwards, by subtracting `toggle` from `0.25`:

```
let toggle;
if (rightSide) {
  if (diff < 0) {
    toggle = 0.15;
  } else {
    toggle = 0.1;
  }
} else {
  if (diff < 0) {
    toggle = 0.1;
  } else {
    toggle = 0.15;
  }
}
const title = 0.25 - toggle;
const lerpFactor = { toggle, title };
```

You could also use a single `if/else` if you wanted, by putting both conditions for `toggle = 0.15` into the `if`:

```
let toggle;
if ((rightSide && diff < 0) || (!rightSide && diff >= 0)) {
  toggle = 0.15;
} else {
  toggle = 0.1;
}
const title = 0.25 - toggle;
const lerpFactor = { toggle, title };
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten like this:

```
var toggleValue, titleValue;

if (rightSide) {
   if (diff < 0) {
      toggleValue = 0.15;
      titleValue = 0.1;
   }
   else {
      toggleValue = 0.1;
      titleValue = 0.15;
   }
}
else
{
   if (diff < 0) {
      toggleValue = 0.1;
      titleValue = 0.15;
   }
   else {
      toggleValue = 0.15;
      titleValue = 0.1;
   }
}

const lerpFactor = {
   toggle: toggleValue,
   title:  titleValue
};
```

There's a lot of duplication, though. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you can change ternary to `if`/`else`:

```
const lerpFactor = {};
if (rightSide) {
  if (diff < 0) {
    lerpFactor.toggle = 0.15;
    lerpFactor.title= 0.1;
  } else {
    lerpFactor.toggle = 0.1;
    lerpFactor.title = 0.15;
  }
} else {
  if (diff < 0) {
    lerpFactor.toggle = 0.1;
    lerpFactor.title= 0.15;
  } else {
    lerpFactor.toggle = 0.15;
    lerpFactor.title = 0.1;
  }
}
```

Then it can be simplified, by removing the repeating code, to:

```
const lerpFactor = {};
if (rightSide ^ (diff < 0)) {
  lerpFactor.toggle = 0.1;
  lerpFactor.title= 0.15;
} else {
  lerpFactor.toggle = 0.15;
  lerpFactor.title= 0.1;
}
```

Where `^` is boolean [`xor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or%5D) operator.

And then we can set default values to shorten the code more:

```
const lerpFactor = { toggle: 0.1, title: 0.1 };
if (rightSide ^ (diff < 0)) lerpFactor.title = 0.15;
else lerpFactor.toggle = 0.15;
```

There you can stop, but I'll also show a variant with another ternary to make it more beautiful, but not so clear to novice:

```
const lerpFactor = { toggle: 0.1, title: 0.1 };
lerpFactor[(rightSide ^ (diff < 0)) ? 'title' : 'toggle'] = 0.15;
```